# Convert nested dictionary to create String Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains key and items model for the values.

`var selectedDic: [String: [Item]] = [:]`

- Actually I am trying to make a string with dictionary key and key has multiple value separated by comma.
- And if I add more values to key it should add values to specific key.
- `price` and `publisher` are keys and `itemId` is the value.

I need this string: `price:10-25;publisher:576,925,1737`

Dictionary Print:

```
[
  "price": [
    Babil.Item(name: Optional("10 - 25"),
    itemId: Optional("10-25"))
  ],
  "publisher": [
    Babil.Item(name: Optional("ABCD"),
    itemId: Optional("576")),
    Babil.Item(name: Optional("DEFG"),
    itemId: Optional("925")),
    Babil.Item(name: Optional("HIJK"),
    itemId: Optional("1737"),
    )
  ]
]
```

My code:

```
 var itemString: [String: String] = [:]
 var str: [String] = []
        
   for (key, value) in selectedDic {
            value.forEach { a in
                if str.firstIndex(of: key) == nil {
                    str.append(a.itemId!)
                }
            }
            
            let final = str.joined(separator: ",")
            itemString.updateValue(final, forKey: key)
            
        }
```

Comment: `let priceStr = itemString["price"]?.compactMap{ $0.name }.joined(separator: ","); let publisherStr = itemString["publisher"]?.compactMap{ $0.itemId } .joined(separator:",");
let finalStr = [priceStr, publisherStr].compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: ";")` or something like that? But it would help to know what's your current output, can there be more than one price? Why use a Dict and not another custom struct? Why `name` AND `itemId` are BOTH optional in `Item`? Is that normal?

Comment: @Larme Thank you first of all. But before creating string it duplicates value to other keys as well.  see - `["price": "10-25", "publisher": "10-25,576,925,1737"] `   10-25 in publisher too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
struct Item {
    let name: String?
    let itemId: String?
}

let dict: [String: [Item]] = ["price": [Item(name: "10-25", itemId: "10-25")],
                              "publisher": [Item(name: "ABCD", itemId: "576"),
                                            Item(name: "DEFG", itemId: "925"),
                                            Item(name: "HIJK", itemId: "1737")]]
```

You could use:

```
var keys = ["price", "publisher"]
let reduced = keys.reduce(into: [String]()) { result, current in
    guard let items = dict[current] else { return }
    let itemsStr = items.compactMap {$0.itemId }.joined(separator: ",")
    result.append("\(current):\(itemsStr)")
}
let finalStr = reduced.joined(separator: ";")
print(finalStr)
```

The idea:
Iterate over the needed keys (and order guaranteed), construct for each keys, the itemsIds list joined by "," and then append that with the key.
Finally, joined all that.

Add-on questions:
Why is `name` and `itemId` optional? Is that normal?

Site note: giving the first part (easily reproducible input) can increase the change of answers, so we don't have to recreate ourselves fake data to check our answers.

Comment: Thank you. `name` and `itemId` yes normal at the moment back end service are on initial phase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
The order of the keys can be different since it is a dictionary and order isn't signficant in a dict

```
print(
    yourDict.map { (key, values) -> String in
        "\(key): \(values.compactMap { $0.itemId }.joined(separator: ","))"
    }.joined(separator: ";") 
)
```